# Would the electrical circuitry of an immersion heater be affected if taken out of the water immediately after switching off?

Tags: heat, metal

I have an immersion heater like this:

[image]

and the tiny instruction manual says

> "Please keep the heater in the water for a minute or two after
>   switching off the current"

...but they haven't explained why. So why would this be required? The coil immersed into the water is a metal jacket which would have a wire passing through it which makes it a bit like a resistor, I assume. Whether it is taken out of the water immediately or after 2 minutes, it will have to cool down and the metals will contract in both situations, and I don't see how it would affect the circuitry and therefore the life of the appliance. Besides, leaving it for two minutes after switching off will allow the water to cool also, which defeats the whole purpose of heating the water.

Comment: Two minutes is certainly over-cautious. If you have a thermocouple and suitable equipment you could observe the externally visible temperature spike if you switch off and immediately remove it - and find a delay that limits the spike to a presumably safe 100C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heater is constructed as an outer tube, an inner heating element, and a ceramic powder electrical insulation packed between them. The ceramic powder is not a good conductor of heat, but adequate for the job. This means that in operation, the central heating element gets *far* hotter than 100C.

There are two issues that could occur if you take the element out of the water as soon as it has boiled.

a) The outer tube is at 100C, the inner wire and all of the ceramic powder is hotter. Once out of the water, air cools the outer tube only poorly, while the excess heat from the insides raises its temperature. If 100C would be damaging in contact with hand, then more than 100C would be even more damaging. It is to protect you from accidentally handling an excessively hot object.

b) If you get used to taking the element out of the water as soon as it has boiled, then you stand a chance of taking it out before you switch off. Deprived of water cooling, the element will heat rapidly and could be damaged within a few seconds. If you get used to leaving it in the water after switching off, that mistake is less likely to occur.

Little damage will occur to the heater if you switch off, then remove it form the water at once.

Answer (score 4):

*a bit like a resistor*

It **is** a resistor.

Although power dissipation stops immediately after you cut the power, there will still be heat stored in the resistor itself inside the metal enclosure. That is called "heat capacity".

If you don't let the heater cool down in the water this residual stored heat warms up the heater instead of the water making it reach temperatures above the boiling point of the water and that could damage the heater. The metal might oxidize and thus change color.

*Besides, leaving it for two minutes after switching off will allow the water to cool also, which defeats the whole purpose of heating the water*

But that residual heat will also heat up the water a bit, if you take the heater out immediately that heat is lost (to the air).